# NPM Windows Path Problems

Tags: windows, node.js, path, gruntjs, npm

I'm trying to get nodejs and npm set up on my machine, but the windows path is having a hard time trying to find the files, and its leading to some strange behaviour.

When my path contains `C:\Users\......\.nvmw\v0.10.21` **npm** commands will work but node, grunt and bower all cannot be found.

If I put `C:\Users\......\.nvmw\v0.10.21\node_modules\npm\bin` into the path the **node**, **grunt** and **bower** commands pass but the npm command fails.

Then, if I try and include both of these in my path I get the three working and a strange error with the npm command, as if it is concatenating the two paths together and looking there:

```
Cannot find module C:\Users\......\.nvmw\node_modules\npm\bin\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
```

Not sure why this is happening and if anybody knows whats going on it would be really helpful,

Thanks

Comment: How did you install node for windows? Using the official installer?

Comment: I installed it using nvmw from the command line.

Comment: You should comment on how you solved it and accept it so that others who might have the same problem know how to fix it!

Comment: I haven't solved the problem as of yet, that I installed it from the command line was my answer to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though this question is pretty old I thought I'd come back and offer the solution that I eventually managed to come up with.

In the end I had two different errors that were happening. First the PATH variable that was set on my work machine had already been polluted quite a lot and was already quite long - so when I tried to install these things it was causing a problem where it would overwrite the end of the path.

I was able to get rid of most of the rouge elements on my PATH which solved part of this problem for me, but I guess making new ENV variables to store parts of paths would be the solution here if there was really a need to have so much on the PATH.

The second issue I was having was pretty simple, in that when I was installing these libraries I was closing and opening the terminal only, which didn't seem to take any effect. To solve this, I restarted my machine after installing and it worked correctly.

I've installed node and npm on a number of different windows and linux machines since asking this question and this problem has not come up since.